# How do I instruct Crystal Reports to use the draft font on my Epson printer?

Tags: fonts, crystal-reports, epson

Espon draft font is automatically installed in Epson Printers but i want to print epson draft font manually . i did find the Epson1 font but couldnot find the Epson draft fonts.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in the question, this font is built into the printer. It is not possible to send a document to the printer in the "draft font". The font exists because the printer uses it when printing in "Draft Mode".

Thus, you ask the printer to use the draft font by requesting it to print in "Draft Mode". That will cause the entire document to print in the draft font. Check your printer's documentation to find out how to do this.

Comment: can't i select epson draft font like any other font.

Comment: No, it's not like any other font. I already explained what and why in my answer... Did you read it?

Comment: ok let me tell you my exact problem. i'm upgrading a system from Foxpro to Visual Studio, "WITH THE SAME PRINTER AT THE SAME TIME" when i print a Report it(FoxPro) gives a font(epson draft) and with visual studio it's font changes(slightly different on same size). i need to have the exact font which was being printed in FoxPro. is that possible?